# What is the excel form to transfer the values ​in the excel table to the sql table in the form of insert and export?

Tags: excel

I have cells containing my EXCEL INFORMATION: name, age and e-mail. I need to connect them to Mysql with the insert into command. What do you think the appropriate formula for this should be? THERE WILL BE FORMULAS IN INSERT INTO(NAME, AGE, EMAIL) VALUES (A1,B1,C1).

`= ( INSERT INTO  tableNAme (name , age , email) VALUES(A1,B1,C1))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.